# A lie theoretic interpretation of $e^\text{cycle} = \text{permutation}$?

Tags: combinatorics, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-groups

It is well known that exponentiating the EGF(exponential generating function) for cycles gives the EGF for permutations: [link here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf). This is something summarized by the slogan `all = exp(connected)`.

I wonder if it is possible to give a lie-theoretic explanation to this phenomenon where we have `group = exp(algebra)`.

Is there some way to relate the "counting" done by the exponential generating function to an *actual* exponential between the Lie group and its algebra? Perhaps there is some way to use the representation theory of $S_n$ to establish some connection? Is this connection one of those near-misses that holds nothing deeper?